# Elastic Beanstalk compared to Heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For my next project i have a choice to between choosing from Elastic Beanstalk or Heroku ? The decision will come down to two things.

1. Deployment, Maintenance setup etc (Heroku is a handsdown winnder)
2. Cost of Scalability. Is there any comparison available of the financial cost of the two. The server app will probably be answering around 100,000 to 500,000 calls a days. What would be the better of the two ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

EBS is actually elastic block store, which would be a reason few people are answering. As for cost of scalability, consider that on heroku your unit of scale is a dyno, whereas elastic beanstalk requires you to step up with whole EC2 instances.